# How to take that data from api and write a function

Tags: ruby, json

Okay, it's been many days. I have been going back and forth with this api, and would like to get the following results.

Here is the problem.

```
uri = URI('https://api.wmata.com/StationPrediction.svc/json/GetPrediction/All')
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form({'api_key' => 'ihaveit',})
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
@response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
    http.request(request)
    @data = JSON.parse @response.body
```

Now i've the @data parsed as JSON. I am trying to write a class Trains and use the following data.

```
{
      "Car": "6",
      "Destination": "SilvrSpg",
      "DestinationCode": "B08",
      "DestinationName": "Silver Spring",
      "Group": "1",
      "Line": "RD",
      "LocationCode": "A01",
      "LocationName": "Metro Center",
      "Min": "3"
    },
```

Here is the code for class Trains

```
class Trains
def initialize(car, destination, destinationcode, destinationname, group, line, locationcode, locationname)
  @car = car
  @destination = destination
  @destinationcode = destinationcode
  @destinationname = destinationname
  @group = group
  @line = locationcode
  @locationname = locationname
end
```

And now im stuck about the next step. I am totally new to api. I can write the following for a static class.

```
  def to_s
      puts(@car + @destination + @destinationcode + @destinationname + @group + @line + @locationname)
   end
   = Trains.new
   puts Train
  end
```

I've got this so far.

```
class TrainLoader < Struct.new(:car, :destination, :destinationcode, :destinationname, :group, :line, :locationcode, :locationname)
    class Trains

    end
    t = Trains.new(@data["Car"],@data["DestinationCode"], @data[DestinationName],@data[Group],@data[Line], @data[LocationCode], @data[LocationName], @data[Min])
```

Comment: What is question here?

Comment: Let me rephrase my question again.

Comment: I see a success request with data, what kind of a function you want to write?

Comment: I would like to see the data from JSON to be converted into Trains class. Hope it helps.

Comment: please format your code snippet, like in my answer, with help me to understand your current problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a class, just write a `to_s` funtcion:

```
class Trains
  def initialize(car, destination, destinationcode, destinationname, group, line, locationcode, locationname)
    @car = car
    @destination = destination
    @destinationcode = destinationcode
    @destinationname = destinationname
    @group = group
    @line = locationcode
    @locationname = locationname
  end

  # inspect attributes with own `to_s` method
  def to_s
    "#{@car} #{@destination} #{@destinationcode} #{@destinationname}"
  end
end
```

Now create an instance of your class:

```
>> train = Trains.new(@data["Car"], @data["Destination"], @data["DestinationCode"])..
>> train.to_s
```

But i can suggest you a more elegant solution, with  [`struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Struct.html):

```
>> data = {
?>       "Car": "6",
?>       "Destination": "SilvrSpg",
?>       "DestinationCode": "B08",
?>       "DestinationName": "Silver Spring",
?>       "Group": "1",
?>       "Line": "RD",
?>       "LocationCode": "A01",
?>       "LocationName": "Metro Center",
?>       "Min": "3"
>>     }
>> class Trains < Struct.new(*data.keys)
#> # create a struct with attributes like keys in data hash `"Cat"` or `"Min"`                  
>> end
>> t = Trains.new(*data.values)
# create instance of Trains class with values from a data hash `"6"`
=> #<struct Trains Car="6", Destination="SilvrSpg", DestinationCode="B08", DestinationName="Silver Spring", Group="1", Line="RD", LocationCode="A01", LocationName="Metro Center", Min="3">
>> t.Car
=> "6"
>>
```

Comment: How can i call on the @data to Trains.new ?

Comment: @manshu sorry, don't understand you question, what you mean `call on the @data to Trains.new` ?

Comment: data from the api is stored in @ data now in order for me to create new train  , how can i use json data that's coming from @ data ?

Comment: `t = Trains.new(@data["Car"], @data["Destination"], @data["DestinationCode"].....)` this initialize a `t` instance with attributes from `@data` hash.

Comment: got it. let me test it.

Comment: @manshu please post it to the question body it's to hard to understand code from comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84043/discussion-between-manshu-and-).